# JQuery JSON Keyset Auto Complete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have the complex json object(multiple hierarchy). I'm planning to create autocomplete using that json.

If I access the parent object like `parent.`, after the period(`.`), only the childObjects of that parent has to be populated in the autocomplete. If I enter the `parentObject.ChildObject.` then the `grandChildObjects` has to be populated in the autocomplete.

For Example, if I have the below json

```
{
  "userInfo":{
    "id":"",
    "firstName":"",
    "lastName":"",
    "middleName":"",
    "dob":"",
    "contact":{
        "email":"",
        "work":"",
        "phone":"",
        "mobile":""
    }
  }
}
```

in the autocomplete, if i enter the `userInfo` with dot like `userInfo.` after the dot, autocomplete has to display only the `id, firstName, lastName, middleName, dob, contact` fields.

If I enter `userInfo.contact.` after the dot, autocomplete has to display `email, work, mobile, phone` fields.

Could you please suggest, how is it possible?

Comment: I suspect something can be done, yet you have not provided a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Do be able to help, we will need to see an example of your attempted code and an example of the data for testing.